# permanent link to a single file in a folder that can be replaced and renamed

Tags: html, pdf, hyperlink, permalinks

I tried to think about it but I can't find good answers for my website. Let say I have a folder (online) with one PDF file in it. I want to have a link to it, no problem.

**Problem :**
Now let say somebody else is going to change that pdf file with another one. The first pdf is deleted and the new pdf file has a different name... so my html link is broken.

**Question :**
*How can i create a link that will open the single pdf file in that folder (no matter if the pdf file is replaced and renamed later) ?*

I'm open to any solution even javascript or using google drive or don't know what other method. The best would be a link that works like http://mywebsite.com/folder/*.pdf or something like that.

THANK YOU & good luck to find the answer:)

Comment: if you can use some server side language like asp.net or php, you can create a web page that can traverse the pdf file in given folder and send it to client, and instead of PDF link you can provide the link for that web page.

Comment: Ok that would be great, but the problem is now on that page that can traverse the pdf file in given folder. How you do that ?

Comment: for that you need to know a little about asp.net or php.

Comment: is there only one file in that folder?

Comment: yes only one file. I do create another folder if I need to put another file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a server-side redirect. [This wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_redirect) explains this and gives snippets for PHP, ASP.NET and JSP. Where you redirect to is an outcome of enumerating the PDF files in your folder.

The page that executes this code is the published URL to your PDF. E.g. http://mywebsite.com/folder/pdf.aspx.

Comment: Ok thank you for idea that seems good but if I understand it correctly, I have to enumerate all the different pdf file name so the link can be maintained.For example if I work on my .htacess file, I will have to modify it when my file is replaced.

Comment: In fact I just want that if the pdf file is replaced the link still work. I don't know what will be the next name of this pdf file, so I can't name it previously in my .htaccess file. Is there no other solution when saying there always will be one file into that one same folder for example ?

Comment: The PDF file name is determined at HTTP request time. So the link will continue to work. You do not have to mainain a .htaccess file.